# Javascript Uncaught TypeError - can't find line in error

Tags: javascript, jquery, cfml

I inherited this project. I added the last 12 lines of code.  The error doesn't have anything to do with what I added but it stops dev tools from stopping on a break point.  The alert in my code works and gives me the correct data. But, I'm not getting the "checked" status on the checkbox I think I'm pointing at.  Hard to debug. I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". It appears right below a script> line. So it doesn't appear to be my code, but I can't find the problem. How can I debug this problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    colortab = function(tabName, color){

        var tabs = ColdFusion.Layout.getTabLayout('mainTab');

        var tab = tabs.getTab(tabName);

        tab.el.dom.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.style.color = color;
    }
    init = function(){
        colortab('tab10', 'red');
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR SHOWS UP IN DEV TOOLS  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //GetCityState = function(z){
            //alert(z.value);
            //$.ajax({
                //type: 'Post',
                //url: 'http://www.zip-info.com/cgi-local/zipsrch.exe',
                //data: 'zip=' + z.value + '&Go=Go',
                //success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //alert('Response ' + response);
                //},
                //error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
                //alert('error ' + errorThrown);
                //}
            //});
        //}

        $('#adminperson').click(function(){
            ColdFusion.Window.show('AdminPersonWindow');
        });

    });

    function SubmitAdminPersons() {
        console.log("adminform " , $("#AdminPersonForm").serialize());
        var AdminStr = $("#AdminPersonForm").serialize();
        $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                url: 'cfc/updates.cfc?method=UpdateAdminPerson',
                data: AdminStr,
                success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //alert('Response ' + response);
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // show error
                alert('error ' + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        ColdFusion.Window.hide('AdminPersonWindow');
        alert('You have to refresh this page to see the new info.');
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".collapseContent").hide();
        //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
        jQuery(".collapseHeader").click(function()
        {
            jQuery(this).next(".collapseContent").slideToggle(500);
        });

        $('#jd_year').change(function() {
            var jdyear = $('#jd_year').val();
            //alert(jdyear);
            if (jdyear){
                $( "#skill_2" ).each(function( i ) {
                    if ( this.val() == "JD" ) {
                        this.checked;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you aren't including the jquery.js source.

Comment: Yes, Jquery is included.  Actually I see (dev tools) jquery-1.3.2.js and jquery.min.js.  I'll see what I can about it.

Comment: I removed all references to jquery-1.3.2.js.  that leaves me with jquery.min.js (v 1.7.1) and the code that was using 1.3.2 is working just fine.  But I still get the same error I was getting before.

Comment: I've removed/consolidated all the script> and /script> tags. The error has moved into the dynamic script that Coldfusion generates and I have no control over.  Isn't there a better way to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this line "// show error" is not commented in your actual code.

Please check it in following code

$(document).ready(function() {

```
//GetCityState = function(z){
        //alert(z.value);
        //$.ajax({
            //type: 'Post',
            //url: 'http://www.zip-info.com/cgi-local/zipsrch.exe',
            //data: 'zip=' + z.value + '&Go=Go',
            //success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //alert('Response ' + response);
            //},
            //error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            **// show error**
            //alert('error ' + errorThrown);
            //}
        //});
    //}
```

Comment: I remove that entire section of comments and still get the same error.